# How to fix these vulnerability "" (CVE-2020-2781) ** Upgrade IBM Java to version 7.0.10.65 "" in rhel 7 server

Tags: linux, rhel7, vulnerabilities

I got this type of  vulnerabilities on a rhel server after scan "(CVE-2020-2781) ** Upgrade IBM Java to version 7.0.10.65 Download and apply the upgrade from: [https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/""](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/%22%22)

Can I fix this vulnerability by install or upgrade the openjdk from  repository
or this need separate RPM to upgrade

current  java version is below -

java -version
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.6.0 - pxa6480**-201***_01(S**))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 2*****_4**** (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - f0b6be7
OMR      - 18d8f94
IBM      - 233dfb5)

Comment: The directions were perfectly clear. Why do you question them?

Comment: Thanks for reply - The Reason is DB folks are saying it should be patch by OS admin but I think there is no patch available in redhat  to patch this but I am not so sure . If package needs to be download and upgrade and then I can say its not my scope

Comment: It doesn't say anything about Red Hat! It says IBM. This is not a Red Hat vulnerability.

Comment: How to patch and who should patch are different questions.

Comment: The finding is for Java 7, but the Java version you show is version 8. https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/java-sdk-downloads-version-80

Answer (score 0):

I guess a kind of SAST scanning has been introduced lately, and you are the administrator which owns the server. The finding indicates that most likely more than one java version is installed on the server, as the standard version installed is for java 8, but the scan result is for java 7.

Either ask for more details (as file locations) from the scan, or scan by yourself for other java files.

It is possible that a certain application has been installed on the server, which brings its own version of Java embedded inside the installation.

Another possibility is that the scan is incorrect - I know SAST scanners that are really bad and detect false or false positive.